# Scrolling top content while scrolling RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I'm developing a native android app and there is something I want to do but don't know how. I have a layout above my recyclerview that can be scrolled and I want it to go up when I scroll the recyclerview or the layout itself, until the recyclerview, which height is wrap content, occupies the screen completely.

What I tried to far is the following:

- Add the above content on a NestedScrollView and added
  `app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"` to
  RecyclerView
  This didn't work, the recyclerview wouldn't expand to occupy the above layout. Each one would have it initial height and just scroll inside that area.

Then I read about NestedScrollView with RecyclerView inside

- Added all content inside the NestedScrollView, including recyclerview. This almost worked especially after adding `setNestedScrollingEnable(true)` but this broke the RecyclerView pattern, all the recyclerview content would be loaded on the start and not as I scroll.

I've added some images to describe what I want to accomplish and here is my layout base:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:fresco="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        >
        <com.facebook.drawee.view.SimpleDraweeView
            android:id="@id/profilePicture"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/profileCircleHeight"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/profileCircleHeight"
            fresco:roundingBorderWidth="1dp"
            fresco:roundingBorderColor="@color/profileCircleBorder"
            fresco:roundAsCircle="true"
            />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/userName"
            />

        <TextView
            android:text="@string/friends"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/userFriends"
        android:background="@color/cardColor"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

Any idea how can I achieve this? I've though about using a different viewholder for the top part but it seams overkill for something this easy and have some performance concerns because in the future I will have a horizontal scroll recyclerview on the above area.

Thanks

PS: Above area is the name I call everything above RecyclerView, in the example case the LinearLayout holding the picture and textview. The toolbar can be ignored for this

[image: Before Scroll]

[image: After scroll]